# How Open Session In View works with jms connection/session?

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, jms

We have a grails web application which accepts http requests and delegates the processing to pub-sub jms using activemq.

Since, the http request are returned after publishing the message to a destination, is the Open Session In View interceptor token closed right after publishing?

When the subscriber starts processing the message from activemq queue (service methods are subscriber here) will the entire transaction(there are multiple transactions in a subscriber service method) be in a single session or whether hibernate template strategy of opening a session for a single transaction and closing it after commit will be used? 
If so, for a single jms message processing, there will be multiple sessions that will be opened and closed?

I have been scratching my head for a while but am unable to get it solved,any help will be useful!

Comment: Are you using any plugins such as the JMS plugin for Grails? This will help answer your question.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore yes we are using grails "jms:1.3" as plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you have several questions here.

Let's start with the first one:

> ... is the Open Session In View interceptor token closed right after publishing?

It is closed as it does normally. When the HTTP request ends. Publishing a JMS message has no impact on this.

Next:

> When the subscriber starts processing the message from activemq queue ...  will the entire transaction be in a single session ... ?

The answer is *it depends*. It depends because you could change the default behavior with your own code. However, if you are following the most common pattern of a single transactional service method to process the message then only one hibernate session (provided by the JMS plugin functionality) and one transaction (provided by your service method) will be used. Both the transaction and the hibernate session will both close

Comment: So, will there be a new hibernate session for each jms connection to broker for recieving messages?
 I have been searching for a relation between jms session and a hibernate session but haven't found anyhing concrete. Any source will be helpful!